# Customizing User roles in Portal for ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-portal

Portal for ArcGIS allows creating custom roles with different privileges defined. Fine. But if I need even more detailed customization?

For example if I need to create a role which can create a map but not an app? Is there a way to separate the item "Content" to Maps and Apps and define different privileges for each?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can create custom roles in your enterprise AGOL site/Portal 10.3 by clicking on the following:

1. Login to enterprise account as an administrator
2. Click 'My Organization'
3. Click 'Edit Settings'
4. Click 'Roles'
5. Click 'Create Roles'
6. Create the custom role
7. Enter in a role name and description.
8. Select a template
9. Customize the role even further by clicking the additional privilages options on and off

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Josh for your detailed answer. I already wen that far and were able to define custom privileges but I need to separate Apps from Maps which is not an option yet.